# Javascript simple timer does not work corectly

Tags: javascript

Please help me with my code.My problem is when the timer is finished, it shows -1:60 instead of showing 0:00.I tried different ways of else statement,but in vain. When I change the condition in if statement to x>0,the timer doesn't go down from 0:60.  Any help will be appreciated. I tried different else, if else statements,nothing helps.
Thank you in advance.

```
<h1  id='session' onClick='general()'>2</h1>
```

JS:

```
 var seconds=60;
 var x=document.getElementById('session').innerHTML-1;
 var t;

 function timer(){
   if(x>=0){
      seconds--; 
      if(seconds<10){
         seconds='0'+seconds;
        };
       if(seconds==0){
           x--;
          seconds=60;
         }
        }
    document.getElementById('session').innerHTML=x+':'+seconds;
 }

  function stoptimer(){
       clearInterval(t);
   }

    var on=true;
       function general(){
          if(on){  
                 on=false;
                t = setInterval(timer,200);
          }else{  
              on=true;
               stoptimer();
         }
       }
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what is your problem, try to write more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Well, my problem  is when the timer is finished, it shows -1:60 instead of showing 0:00.I tried differnet ways of else statement,but in vain. When I change the condition in if statement to  x>0,the timer doesn't go down from 0:60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is all because of the timer funtion, so I've made a few changes to your function, and rewritten it. I ran it in the jsfiddle and it's working.

```
function timer(){        
   if(x>=0 && flag==false){
      seconds--; 
      if(seconds<10){
         seconds='0'+seconds;
        };
       if(seconds==0){
           x--;
          seconds=60;
         }
        }
    if (x == -1){
     flag=true;
     x = 0;
     seconds = '00';
    }
    document.getElementById('session').innerHTML=x+':'+seconds;
}
```

Make sure you take a global variable `var flag=false;` in order for this function properly.
Here is the link for the jsfiddle I created: https://jsfiddle.net/35w4nkzm/1/

I hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I created a fiddle for you, it countdowns the timer from 60 seconds to 00.

**Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/njw73naj/

**HTML**

```
<h1>
 <span id="min">0</span>
 :
 <span id="sec">00</span>
</h1>
```

**JS**

```
var seconds = 60,
    secondDom = document.getElementById("sec");

secondDom.innerHTML = seconds;

var countdown = function(){
    seconds--;
    if(seconds < 0){
      clearInterval(timer);
    }else{
      secondDom.innerHTML = (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
    }
}

var timer = setInterval(countdown,1000);
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Thank you very much,it really helped.:)

Answer (score 0):

I've removed certain unnecessary things from your code. though,
you should know it's not really 2 minutes. my "setInterval" is based
on your original setInterval.

HTML:

```
<h1  id='session' onclick='general()'>1</h1>
```

JS:

```
<script>
var seconds = 60;
var x = document.getElementById('session').innerHTML;

var t;

function timer(){

    if (x === 0 && seconds === 0)
    {
        stoptimer(t);
    }

    else if(seconds === 0){
        seconds = 60;
        x--;
    }

    else{
        seconds--;
    }

document.getElementById('session').innerHTML = x + ':' + seconds;
}

function stoptimer(){
    clearInterval(t);
}

var on = true;

function general(){
    if(on){  
        on=false;
        t = setInterval(timer,200);
    }else{  
        on=true;
        stoptimer();
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank  you  very much man, for your great effort.Highly appreciated.